# Marklogic - Use Options file from back end

Tags: marklogic

I am currently working with the default **/v1/search** endpoint, using an **options=search.xml** argument.

I am working on moving functionality to the backend into a custom extended endpoint.

Right now, I have copied the options file into the module itself. Is there anyway to access the already stored options file on the server and use that instead of hardcoding the options? There will inevitably be more than 1 endpoint that may want to use the same options, and do not want to hard code into each endpoint.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to [PUT or POST your options to /v1/config/query/[name]](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_93884). Then you can specify the name of your options file in your request to /v1/search.

---

Edit: more detail in response to comment

Assuming you uploaded the options with the name "search", then your call to /v1/search would look like this:

```
http://{server}:{port}/v1/search?options=search&q=my+query
```

You can verify that your options are properly installed by going to [/v1/config/query](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/config/query).

Comment: That is how I am doing it now, I would like to call the already configured options file from an extended service

Answer (score 0):

The options file is stored in the modules database.  To read it, you would need to use xdmp:invoke-function() or another eval or invoke approach to execute fn:doc() in the modules database.

Both for maintainability and performance, keeping the options definition in your extension might be best.

One footnote:  You've probably noticed but, in case not, a /v1/search request can send a combined search:search element with both the query and options.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the guidance. I will look into the evaluation functions as mentioned. I am doing the search:search on the backend so I can look up related data from a knowledge graph to include in the search request... Maybe I will think about maintaining individual options per service, but will loko at invoke function first